# Error throwing while loading GridPanel on button click

Tags: ext.net

I am getting a javascript error while trying to load GridPanel on a button click. The same function is working while calling on page_load event.

Code:

```
    private DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
       DataTable table = new DataTable();

       table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
           new DataColumn("Company")   { ColumnName = "Company",    DataType =        typeof(string) },
           new DataColumn("Price")     { ColumnName = "Price",      DataType =    typeof(double) },
           new DataColumn("Change")    { ColumnName = "Change",     DataType =  typeof(double) },
           new DataColumn("PctChange") { ColumnName = "PctChange",  DataType = typeof(double) },
           new DataColumn("PctChange") { ColumnName = "LastChange", DataType = typeof(DateTime) }
       });

       foreach (object[] obj in this.Data)
       {
           table.Rows.Add(obj);
       }

       return table;
    }

    private object[] Data
    {
       get
       {
           DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

           return new object[]
           {
               new object[] { "3m Co", 71.72, 0.02, 0.03, now },
               new object[] { "Alcoa Inc", 29.01, 0.42, 1.47, now },
               new object[] { "Altria Group Inc", 83.81, 0.28, 0.34, now },
               new object[] { "American Express Company", 52.55, 0.01, 0.02, now },
               new object[] { "American International Group, Inc.", 64.13, 0.31, 0.49, now },
               new object[] { "AT&T Inc.", 31.61, -0.48, -1.54, now },
               new object[] { "Boeing Co.", 75.43, 0.53, 0.71, now },
               new object[] { "Caterpillar Inc.", 67.27, 0.92, 1.39, now },
               new object[] { "Citigroup, Inc.", 49.37, 0.02, 0.04, now },
               new object[] { "E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company", 40.48, 0.51, 1.28, now },
               new object[] { "Exxon Mobil Corp", 68.1, -0.43, -0.64, now },
               new object[] { "General Electric Company", 34.14, -0.08, -0.23, now },
               new object[] { "General Motors Corporation", 30.27, 1.09, 3.74, now },
               new object[] { "Hewlett-Packard Co.", 36.53, -0.03, -0.08, now },
               new object[] { "Honeywell Intl Inc", 38.77, 0.05, 0.13, now },
               new object[] { "Intel Corporation", 19.88, 0.31, 1.58, now },
               new object[] { "International Business Machines", 81.41, 0.44, 0.54, now },
               new object[] { "Johnson & Johnson", 64.72, 0.06, 0.09, now },
               new object[] { "JP Morgan & Chase & Co", 45.73, 0.07, 0.15, now },
               new object[] { "McDonald\"s Corporation", 36.76, 0.86, 2.40, now },
               new object[] { "Merck & Co., Inc.", 40.96, 0.41, 1.01, now },
               new object[] { "Microsoft Corporation", 25.84, 0.14, 0.54, now },
               new object[] { "Pfizer Inc", 27.96, 0.4, 1.45, now },
               new object[] { "The Coca-Cola Company", 45.07, 0.26, 0.58, now },
               new object[] { "The Home Depot, Inc.", 34.64, 0.35, 1.02, now },
               new object[] { "The Procter & Gamble Company", 61.91, 0.01, 0.02, now },
               new object[] { "United Technologies Corporation", 63.26, 0.55, 0.88, now },
               new object[] { "Verizon Communications", 35.57, 0.39, 1.11, now },
               new object[] { "Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.", 45.45, 0.73, 1.63, now }
           };
       }
     }
     private void createDynamicGrid()
     {
       Store store1 = new Store();
       GridPanel grid = this.GrdPanel;
       Ext.Net.Model model = new Model();
       for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       {
           ModelField modelField = new ModelField();
           if (i == 0)
               modelField.Name = "Company";
           else
               modelField.Name = "Price";

           model.Fields.Add(modelField);

       }

       store1.Model.Add(model);
       store1.DataSource = this.GetDataTable();
       store1.DataBind();
       grid.Store.Add(store1);
       grid.SelectionModel.Add(new RowSelectionModel { Mode = SelectionMode.Single });
       grid.ColumnModel.Columns.Add(new ColumnBase[] { 
           new Column 
           {
               Text = "Company",
               DataIndex = "Company",
               Flex = 1
           },
           new Column
           {
               Text = "Price",
               DataIndex = "Price"

           }
       });
       grid.Render();
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
       createDynamicGrid();
    }
```

Designer View:

```
        <ext:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" Icon="FeedMagnify" X="150"
               Y="10">
               <DirectEvents>
                   <Click OnEvent="btnSearch_Click" />
               </DirectEvents>
           </ext:Button>
```

If I am calling createDynamicGrid() on page_load then it is working fine.

Error message: "Microsoft JScript compilation error: Expected identifier"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following examples will be helpful: http://examples.ext.net/#/XRender/Basic/Add_Items/

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagprefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>
    <script runat="server">
    public void Button_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateGrid().Render(this.Container1, RenderMode.AddTo);
    }

    public GridPanel CreateGrid()
    {
        // string id = parameters["id"];

        List<object> data = new List<object>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            data.Add(new { ID = "P" + i, Name = "Product " + i });
        }

        GridPanel grid = new GridPanel
            {
                Height = 200,
                EnableColumnHide = false,
                Store = 
                    { 
                        new Store 
                            { 
                                Model = {
                                    new Model {
                                        IDProperty = "ID",
                                        Fields = 
                                            {
                                                new ModelField("ID"),
                                                new ModelField("Name")
                                            }
                                    }
                                },
                                DataSource = data
                            }
                    },
                ColumnModel =
                    {
                        Columns = 
                            { 
                                new Column { Text = "Products's Name", DataIndex = "Name" }
                            }
                    }
            };

        return grid;
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    <ext:Container runat="server" ID="Container1"></ext:Container>

    <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Create grid" OnDirectClick="Button_Click"></ext:Button>
</body>
</html>
```